# how to refactor or fix circular reference in this case? java

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have read a parent Class called MyClass
code like this,

```
 public class MyClass extends CompositeObject{
    protected Map<String,MyAttibute> attributes = new       

    HashMap<String,MyAttribute>
    .....

 }
```

In MyAttribute Class,
 Code like this

```
public class MyAttibute extends MyObject 
{
   private MyClass definedOnClass;//point to its parentClass

}
```

This actually is a circular reference.Which makes trouble when you do deep serlization and equals. And it may not be a good design.How to avoid it? And after fixing it, we can still easily find the parentClass from its attribute.

P.S. I see another two classes design

```
public class Transaction{
   private ChangeManager parentManager;
   ....
   public Transaction(ChangeManager parentManager)
} 

public class ChangeManager {
  //record transaction when commit
  private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
  Transaction currentTransaction;
  ....  
}
```

Do you think this kind of design is good? Why?
As you can see the domains these classes are defining on are quite common.
So can anyone share some insight about it? Is it harmful to let Transaction know its ChangeManager and let MyAttributes know its MyClass in their properties? Any comments are welcome. Cons and pros.

Comment: If I understand you correctly your parent class has a reference to a child of itself? (it's not totally clear for me so ignore this if that's not the case) Oh goodness, no that's absolutely certainly no good idea - and the problems with serializing are only the icing on top of a horrible design. A class should never need or assume knowledge of its children

Comment: @Voo,We meet this problem when handling the serialization. But the data model is not designed by us. So this is the problem.

Comment: Ok that's not really clear from the question (especially the part "is this a good design?") - should go more along the lines of "How do we work around this horrible design" ;) But if definedOnClass is the subclass itself I don't see how you can fix it (in that case there's no recursive base case); if it isn't it should work fine I'd think - what's the exact error?

Comment: The work around is already there.That is use a IdentityHashMap to record the object that has serialized. And when meet circular reference, it writes the map key for that object. But I want to see more advices or suggestions how to design these classes in a nicer way in both of the cases.

Comment: did you mean `MyAttibute extends MyClass`?

Comment: @Bohemian MyAttibute does not extend MyClass. Actually My parentClass has a Map of Map<AtributeId,MyAttibute>. And in MyAttribute, there is a reference point back to MyClass.Which becomes a circular reference here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the MyAttibute as a child logically independent of the parent so attr1.equals(attr2) doesn't involve the respective parents (same with serialization; don't include it in the stream) and you can keep the definedOnClass property

or you can use a different equals method when testing from MyClass

```
public class MyAttibute extends MyObject 
{
   private NgcClass definedOnClass;//point to its parentClass

   public boolean equals(Object o){
       if(o instanceof MyAttibute){
           MyAttibute other = (MyAttibute)o;

           if(!this.definedOnClass.equals(other.definedOnClass))
                return false;//when not from the same parent they are never the same

           return this.equals2(other);
       }
       return false;
   }

   //this one should then be called from MyClass
   public boolean equals2(MyAttibute o){
       //check equality without worrying about definedOnClass
   }
}
```

note that the default serialization of java's objectstreams can handle circular references

Comment: I don't think your code can work.this.definedOnClass.equals(other.definedOnClass) this call on MyClass's equals method, which will end up with StackOverflowError.

Comment: @clark not if MyClass calls MyAttibute.equals2() instead of equals

Comment: @ratchel Ok I understood. you split the equals into two parts.The idea is good. But can the code style be a bit cleaner?